# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError While Trying to Modify a Jar and rebuiling again

Tags: java, instagram

I tried to use `JInstagram` java wrapper sachin-handiekar  to access Instagram Api.

`JInstagram` Jar uses Long as dataType for Media ID parameters but instagram has changed media Id to something like `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxx` format , which is obviously a `String` datatype. So I am trying to change the Source and successfully recreate the jar with the following changes

```
public MediaCommentsFeed getMediaComments(**long mediaId**) throws InstagramException {
        ...
}

public MediaCommentsFeed getMediaComments(**String mediaId**) throws InstagramException {
    ...
}
```

But When I tried to run the application with the new jar, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jinstagram.Instagram.getMediaComments(**Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jinstagram/entity/comments/MediaCommentsFeed;**
    at com.shoewars.controller.InstagramController.hanldeInstagramOauthCallBackResponse(InstagramController.java:92)
```

Have I missed anything while recreating the jar?

Comment: are you sure that you are using the new jar? It does not have the new method (but presumably the old one).

Comment: Apparently you are using new jar at compile time while old jar at runtime.

Comment: no i have removed the old jar , and added the new jar , even at compile time tat method exists, but when i run it , i get this error

Comment: You are mixing jar versions somehow. Run your code with the `-verbose:class` switch to see where the jar is loaded from.